# Кнопка произвольной формы в виде картинки в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Изучаю C# и сразу пишу музыкальный плеер (Для тренировки сам себе придумал такое вот задание). Меня не устраивают базовые кнопки в windows form и мне хочется добавить произвольную кнопку, которую я нарисовал в photoshop. Как мне добавить ее на форму и что бы при наведении и нажатии на нее она выделялась и дёргалась так же как и стандартные кнопки? Либо как наложить на стандартную кнопку текстуру, что бы эта текстура была полностью на всю кнопку, а не только внутри этой кнопки, оставляя вокруг текстуры некрасивый ободок?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но для таких манипуляций надо переопределить базовый класс `Component` и его средствами отрисовывать нужную форму кнопки и реализовывать нужный функционал

Comment: @Chloroform а может есть ссылка на конкретный пример этого или может опишите здесь как это сделать?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [в этой книге](https://webanetlabs.net/publ/12-1-0-120), но предупреждаю сразу: реализовывать свои кастомные контролы задача не тревиальная и может вызвать покраснение глаз, для обучения лучше начать с более простых примеров

Comment: 0. Отказаться от WinForms и изучить WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо кнопки используйте картинку. А при или отпускании и нажатии просто меняйте `Control.BackgroundImage`

```
  private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //кнопка в момент нажатия ЛКМ
    {
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("path");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //кнопка в момент отпускания ЛКМ
    {
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("path");
    }
  private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) // кнопка при наведении на нее курсора
    {
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("path");
    }

  private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) // кнопка когда курсор отведен
    {
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("path");
    }
```

Способ прямо скажем не особо хороший, но зато очень простой. Если кто знает лучше, отпишитесь - буду благодарен )

Comment: У меня картинка формата png, как сделать так что бы именно при наведении на нарисованную область она действовала, а то при таком добавлении, даже если нажимать на пустую область около картинки, срабатывает кнопка?

Comment: @Sanvirtus обработайте события `MouseEnter` - наведение и `MouseLeave` отвод курсора.

Answer (score 2):

1-вариант.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Bitmap b=new Bitmap("image.png");
button3.BackgroundImage = b;
button3.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;//если надо
button3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
button3.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button3.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
button3.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
button3.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
button3.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
button3.Text = "";
}

private void button3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
System.Drawing.Rectangle r = button3.ClientRectangle;
r.Inflate(-10, -10); //исходя из вашего рисунка и размера кнопки подберите нужные числа
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, r);//после нужного вам результата замените - Pens.Transparent
r.Inflate(1, 1);
gp.AddEllipse(r);
button3.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(gp);
}
```

2-вариант. Проверить каждое нажатие кнопки мыши. Только здесь размер рисунка и кнопки должны быть одинаковыми. Или в начале при `(Bitmap)button3.BackgroundImage` вы должны изменить размер рисунка.

```
private void button3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
System.Drawing.Color cl = ((Bitmap)button3.BackgroundImage).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
if (cl.A == 0 && cl.R == 0 && cl.G == 0 && cl.B == 0) //если Transparent
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing");
else 
    MessageBox.Show("ToDo");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах кнопки должно быть свойство Image (или как-то так). Туда положи свою картинку

Comment: Я так делал. Но текстура ложится во внутрь кнопки и остаются вокруг данной картинки ободок кнопки, который портит всю картину.

Comment: Ну как вариант, можешь использовать PictureBox, при нажатии на который будет выполняться какое-то действие. Можно так же при нажатии менять картинку, а при отпускании кнопки мыши возвращать обратно исходную

Comment: Можете привести пример либо дать ссылку на такой пример?

Comment: Сейчас доступа нет к программе, поэтому по памяти расскажу, что помню. Добавляешь PictureBox на форму. В коде конструктора пропиши путь к изображению. В событиях PictureBox (это в редакторе форм выделяешь элемент и там где свойства есть картинка с молнией) находишь  то ли MousePress, то ли MouseDown, то ли MousePressed (точно не помню). Жмешь по нему два раза, в коде появится обработчик события. Там пишешь код на изменение изображения.

Comment: Затем возвращаешься в события и ищешь что-то похожее на MouseUp или MouseReleased, так же два раза жмешь. В появившемся обработчике устанавливаешь обратно старую картинку и выполняешь необходимое действие. Как-то так. Извиняюсь за неточности, сейчас нет возможности посмотреть программу

Comment: У меня картинка формата png, если так реализовывать, то при наведении на не нарисованную область она будет действовать? Или же будет действовать только при наведении на нарисованную область? Мне бы хотелось второй вариант

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]